# Passing arguments to the constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have terrible coding habits that I picked up from bad code, however I'm working to try and fix those issues. My primary issue is trying to pass the initial arguments through the constructor, I haven't coding in Java for a year, so let me know everything that's wrong!

```
public class AccountHolder {

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        //Introduce scanner
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //Used to take input from user
           System.out.println("Welcome to the bank program! Can you tell me your current balance?");

       input = sc.nextDouble();
       AccountHolder(input);
      }

        // Introduce private field members
        private static double annualInterestRate; //Constant to hold annual interest rate
        private static double fee; // Constant to hold the withdrawal fee
        private double balance; // variable to hold the balance
        private double rateUpdate; // variable to hold the value to update the rate
        private static double input; // variable to hold user input
        private double test; // variable to test whether or not user will drop below $100.

        // introduce a DecimalFormat object
        DecimalFormat twoPlace = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); // Used to keep values to 2 significant figures.

        // Introduce public methods

        public AccountHolder(double input) 
        {   
            balance = input;
        }

        public void deposit(double input)
        { 
            balance = balance + input;
            System.out.println("Your new balance is: $" + twoPlace.format(balance));
        }

        public void withdrawl(double input)
        {
            test = balance;
            balance = balance - input;

            if (balance < 100.0)
            {
                balance = balance + input;
                System.out.println("Your balance is not allowed to drop below $100.00. Please try again when you have more funds.");
            }

            if (test >= 500 && balance < 500)
            {
                balance = balance - fee;
                System.out.println("You have been charged an additional $50 for dropping below $500.00.");
            }

            System.out.println("Your new balance is: $" + twoPlace.format(balance));
        }



        public void monthlyInterest()
        {
            balance += balance * (annualInterestRate / 12.0);
        }

        public static void modifyMonthlyInterest(double rateUpdate)
        {
            annualInterestRate = rateUpdate;
            while (annualInterestRate <= 0 || annualInterestRate >= 1.0)
            {
                System.out.println("Error! Interest rates must be between 0 and 1. We need to keep our money!");
                annualInterestRate = sc.nextDouble();
            }

        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return String.format("$%.2f", balance);

        }



}
```

Comment: you should probably move this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and be more precise what you have trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
AccountHolder(input);
```

you need to do

```
new AccountHolder(input);
```

When you lack the "new", it is interpreted as a method call. With "new" it is interpreted as a call to the constructor.

PS: I'd like to advise you to look into scope of variables. E.g. you could define the "input" variable inside of the "main" method and not as a static class variable. This improves readability of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This is your constructor:

```
public AccountHolder(double input) {   
        balance = input;
 }
```

and you are passing the parameter like:

```
AccountHolder(input);
```

you are missing to use the keyword **new** to actually create a new instance of that class...

like

```
AccountHolder myHolder =  new  AccountHolder(input);
```

Comment: Also, you should consider using an integer variable to keep track of the number of cents, rather than using a double variable to keep track of the number of dollars (or whatever currency unit you are using). You will find that using doubles will cause lots of rounding and truncation headaches later on.

Comment: Thanks....could be, I didnt do an inspection of the code, just focused on the constructor related issue...

Comment: Thank you for the help and the advice! I appreciate it a lot.

Also, we have to use double for this project, but I'll definitely keep that in mind for personal programming.